# Unclear whether values are being saved to db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Part of a `create` method in my controller is:

```
if @organization.relationships && @organization.relationships.where('member = ?', true).any?
  @organization.users.where('member = ?', true).each do |single|
    single.create_digest
    debugger
  end
end
```

As you can see I've been testing with the `debugger`. In the `debugger` I'm experiencing the following strange behaviour. `single` and `organization.users` both display the details/values of the same user. However these values differ between when I examine using `single` and when I use `organization.users` in the `debugger`. For `single` the user does have values for `activation_digest` and `activation_sent_at`, while they are `nil` when I look at `organization.users`.

Can anyone explain this behaviour? The `nil` values are a problem since `single` isn't available outside the `if statement`. It's not clear to me whether the value have or have not been saved to the db.

P.S. The model method being used:

```
def create_digest
  create_activation_digest
  update_attribute(:activation_digest, self.activation_digest)
  update_columns(activation_sent_at: Time.zone.now)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you query for models in Rails (users in your case), each distinct query gives back separate copies of those models.

So for example, the users returned by this query:

```
@organization.users.where('member = ?', true)
```

Will be separate copies of the users that are returned by this slightly different query (I assume this is what you run in the debugger):

```
@organization.users
```

If you modify one copy of the user and save the modifications to the database, it will not automatically propagate those modifications to the other copy of the user. The other copy still has the (now out of date) data that was returned when you first ran the query.

To verify that the changes were actually persisted to the database, you can force Rails to refresh the user object with the latest data from the database by calling `reload`. For example:

```
# These are two different in-memory copies of the same user
user = @organization.users.where('member = ?', true).first
user_copy = User.find(user.id)

user.create_digest

# The copy is now out of date
user_copy.activation_sent_at # => nil

# Refresh the copy from the database
user_copy.reload
user_copy.activation_sent_at # => 2015-08-02 21:00:50 -0700
```